# How to filter and checked matches conditionally with multiple fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sorting, arraylist

How to filter and checked matches  conditionally with multiple fields passing in string;
i have a request as like below:

```
{
name: "abc",
email: "",
phone: "123456",
match: "phone"
}
```

In that case i have to filtered array and get match phone objects in response and
i have an array as like below

```
[{name: "abc", email: "abc@gmail.com",phone:"123456"}, {name: "abc", email: "abc@gmail.com", phone:"1236"}, {name: "pqr", email: "pqr@gmail.com", phone:"123456"} ]
```

in that case my expected output as like below

```
[{name: "abc", email: "abc@gmail.com",phone:"123456"}, {name: "pqr", email: "abc@gmail.com", phone:"123456"} ]
```

Note: my filter condition would be change as per the match string it could be on

```
1st request type
{
email: "pqr@gmail.com",
phone: "123456",
match: "phone,email"
}

Result:
[{name: "pqr", email: "pqr@gmail.com", phone:"123456"}]

2nd request type
{
name: "abc",
email: "abc@gmail.com",
phone: "1236",
match: "phone,email"
}

Result:
[ {name: "abc", email: "abc@gmail.com", phone:"1236"}]
```

name,phone or phone or email or name,email,phone or name only

in that case i have to manipulate filter based on match string

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+filter+multiple+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't understand 100% of your question, I believe that the code below can help you.

```js
const data = [
  {name: "abc", email: "abc@gmail.com",phone:"123456"}, 
  {name: "abc", email: "abc@gmail.com", phone:"1236"}, 
  {name: "pqr", email: "pqr@gmail.com", phone:"123456"} 
]

const options = {
  name: "abc",
  email: "",
  phone: "123456",
  match: "phone"
}

function filter(data,options){
    const keys = options.match.split(',')
    return data
    .filter(item=>{
        return keys
        .map(key=>item[key] === options[key])
        .every(check => check)
    })
}

const test = filter(data,options)

console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function, `filterArr(arr, cond)` that can be used to test every condition on the fields specified by `condition.match` property as follows:

```js
const
      input = [{name: "abc", email: "abc@gmail.com",phone:"123456"}, {name: "abc", email: "abc@gmail.com", phone:"1236"}, {name: "pqr", email: "pqr@gmail.com", phone:"123456"} ],
      
      cond1 = {name: "abc", email: "", phone: "123456", match: "phone"},
      
      cond2 = {email: "pqr@gmail.com", phone: "123456", match: "phone,email"},
      
      filterArr = (arr, cond) => arr.filter(item => cond.match.split(',').every(c => cond[c] === item[c])),
      
      output1 = filterArr(input,cond1),
      
      output2 = filterArr(input,cond2);
      
console.log( output1 );
console.log( output2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to filter out the objects from an array based on the `filterObject` properties available in the `match` property of the filter object.

If my understanding is correct, You can achieve this with the help of [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method along with the [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Live Demo **:**

```js
const arr = [
  {name: "abc", email: "abc@gmail.com", phone:"123456"}, 
  {name: "abc", email: "abc@gmail.com", phone:"1236"},
  {name: "pqr", email: "pqr@gmail.com", phone:"123456"}
];

const filterObj = {
  email: "pqr@gmail.com",
  phone: "123456",
  match: "phone,email"
};

const matchFilterFields = filterObj.match.split(',');

const res = arr.filter(obj => {
  return matchFilterFields.every(field => filterObj[field] === obj[field])
});

console.log(res);
```